# How to open a window after query is executed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working with Ajax y JQuery to precess my data.

What I'm try to do is to save data and just when the process is completed sucesfully, it print a ticket in a new window but It just save the data and don't open anything else.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#formRenta").on("submit", function(e){
                debugger;
                e.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this);
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formRenta"));
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/insert/insert_renta.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (html) {  
                        var resultado = html.indexOf("Éxito");
                        if (resultado) {
                            document.getElementById("formRenta").reset();
                            new PNotify({
                                title: 'Éxito',
                                text: 'El Contrato de Renta fue creado exitosamente.',
                                type: 'success'
                            });
                            var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
                            for(i=1; i < 50; i++){
                                table.deleteRow(i);
                            }
                        //SI EL QUERY NO SE EJECUTO EXITOSAMENTE
                        } else {
                            new PNotify({
                                title: 'Error',
                                text: 'Hubo un problema al intentar agregar el Contrato de Renta, intentelo de nuevo.',
                                type: 'error'
                            });
                        }
                    }       
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not opening a new window because you've done nothing to open a new window. You'd need to submit a form to `target="_blank"`, use `window.open`, something like that. But do you *really* want to do an ajax call followed by opening a window that turns around and submits a new form? That seems quite awkward.

Comment: I noticed your php `<script>` tag is not formated correctly. it should be `<script>(function(){document.getElementById("formRecibo").submit();})();</script>`

Comment: T.J Crowder,  i just try with the window open but it did work. I understand what you are saying about why im using ajax if i want to open a new window but i need it because the windows i want to open is just to print the ticket. Once i print it and close it, i want to still be in the same windows to do other things.